# Loop through method calls with varying parameters

Tags: java

It seems that there should be a way to write the product() calls with a for() loop.  I cannot figure out how to do it.  Does anybody know of a way?

```
// store numbers
int[] i = { 1, 7, 2, 4, 6, 54, 25, 23, 10, 65 };

System.out.println(product(i[0]));
System.out.println(product(i[0], i[1]));
........
System.out.println(product(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8], i[9]));

public static int product(int... num) {...}
```

I already have product written, I just need to call product with arguments from product(i[0]) to product(i[0], i[1], i[2]..., [9]).

Final code:

```
// Calculate product of any amount of numbers
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // create Scanner for input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // store numbers
    int[] array = { 1, 7, 2, 4, 6, 14, 25, 23, 10, 35 };

    for (int j = 1 ; j <= array.length; j++) {

        // Construct a temporary array with the required subset of items
        int[] tmp = new int[j];

        // Copy from the original into the temporary
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, tmp, 0, j);

        // Make a call of product()
        System.out.println(product(tmp));

    }   // end for
}   // end method main

public static int product(int... num)
{
    // product
    int product = 1;

    // calculate product
    for(int i : num)
        product *= i;

    return product;

}   // end method product
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a temporary array of `int`s with the required number of items, copy the sub-array of `i` into that temporary array, and then pass it to `product` like this:

```
for (int count = 1 ; count <= i.length() ; count++) {
    // Construct a temporary array with the required subset of items
    int[] tmp = new int[count];
    // Copy from the original into the temporary
    System.arraycopy(i, 0, tmp, 0, count);
    // Make a call of product()
    System.out.println(product(tmp));
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat what I am looking for, but my assignment wants me to call a method with varying amounts of arguments, such as product(i[0]), product(i[0], i[1]), etc.  It would be very handy to use ... symbols, as in (for(int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) System.out.println(product(i[0]..., i[j]));

Comment: @user2509848 This is exactly what is going to happen when you run the code from the answer: variable number of arguments is a "syntactic sugar" on top of creating an array, i.e. when you do `product(i[0], i[1], i[2])`, compiler produces `product(new int[] {i[0], i[1], i[2]})` behind the scenes before making the call.

Comment: OK.  I will ask my teacher if that is alright.  By the way, when I checked your code, my IDE could not find arrayCopy.  What do I need to import?

Comment: @user2509848 I mistyped the name, it's `arraycopy` in all-lowercase, not camelCase ([link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)).

Comment: My instructor wrote back and said that this was acceptable.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through and keep track of each product result, then place those values in a new array.  Finally, call product method on the newly created array with all products.

```
int[] listOfProducts = new int[i.length];
int [] tempArray;
for(int x = 0; x<i.length; x++){
    //copy i[0] to i[x] into tempArray
    System.arraycopy(i, 0, tempArray, 0, x+1);
    listOfProducts[x] = product(tempArray);
}
System.out.println(product(listOfProducts));
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I just want to call product with arguments from product(i[0]) to product(i[0], i[1], i[2]..., [9]).  I already have product written, but the form said I had too much code to post it.  I will clarify my question now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to write a `product` method with a variable number of arguments. This can be achieved by using the `...` syntax, which will make your method take any number of arguments of the given type, and allow you to handle them as an array inside the method.
E.g.:

```
public static int product (int... numbers) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        product *= number;
    }
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I actually have the product() method written - sorry I didn't clarify that better, but it wouldn't let me post all my code.  I want to call product with arguments from product(i[0]) to product(i[0], i[1], i[2]..., [9]).

Comment: @user2509848 Take a look at my method's definition. With the `int...` syntax, you can call it with any number of `int`s  without having to overload it.

Comment: @user2509848 disregard my last comment, I just understood what I misread in your original question.